# S3 url changed after first request made through aws-sdk in nodejs, why?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am uploading images in the s3 bucket using aws-sdk in NodeJS. But after the first request, the URL changes. URL generated on first request is

```
https://<bucket-name>.s3.amazonaws.com/1Z550EY71395210665.png
```

and on subsequent requests the URL given is:

```
https://<bucket-name>.s3.amazonaws.com/1Z550EY71392070796.png
```

The s3 bucket is public.

I want to get this URL every time:

```
https://.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/1Z550EY71395865100.png
```

Comment: Can you share your code. The file name should be in your control, so the undesired result must have something to do with the logic of your code.

Comment: sorry I typed the URL's in message incorrectly, the url I get on subsequent requests is : `https://bucket-name.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/1Z550EY71395865100.png` and I want the same for every request. As you can see, It's not about the name of the file but this URL does contain the region, but the first url do not.

Comment: Probably has something to do with the S3 bucket URL convention change starting January 30, 2019.  See this:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html#create-bucket-intro